# Добавить кнопки вперед назад для прокрутки изображениий в галерее

Tags: javascript

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста написать кнопки управления для портфолио. Хочется использовать чистый JS.  Есть вот такой код html

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <h1>Некоторые примеры работ</h1>

    <!-- START IMAGE GaLLERY -->
    <!-- <h2 style="text-align:center">Advanced Image Gallery</h2> -->
    <div id="zoom">
        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/tsagency.png" alt="tsagency" class="imgshow">
                <div class="desc">TS agency</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/Photographer.png" alt="Photographer" class="imgshow">
                <div class="desc">Photographer</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/Photographer2.png" alt="Photographer 2" class="imgshow">
                <div class="desc">Photographer2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/jewelry_shop.png" alt="jewelry_shop" class="imgshow">
                <div class="desc">Jewelry shop</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/sitelightshop.png" alt="site lightshop"  class="imgshow">
                <div class="desc">Light shop</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/capcakes.png" alt="capcakes" class="imgshow">
                <div class="desc">Kate Capcakes</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/A1velocity.png" alt="A1velocity" class="imgshow" >
                <div class="desc">A1 Velocity</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/1.png" alt="Who`s involved" class="imgshow" >
                <div class="desc">Who`s involved</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="responsive">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/2_photo design.png" alt="jewelry_shop" class="imgshow">
                <div class="desc">Phoho design</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">X</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- end OF image gallery -->
    </div><!-- id="zoom" -->
</div><!--the end of id="portfolio" -->
```

Есть вот такой js код

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//image  gallery
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Get all images and insert the clicked image inside the modal
// Get the content of the image description and insert it inside the modal image caption
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('imgshow');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   images[i].onclick = function(){
       modal.style.display = "block";
       modalImg.src = this.src;
       modalImg.alt = this.alt;
       captionText.innerHTML = this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
   }
}

</script>
```

Нужно функцию вперед и назад из указанного списка изображений. плагины не хочу брать, кучу всего перечитала, пересмотрела, не работают все мои варианты.

Comment: А чем вам готовые решения не нравятся?  Например такие   http://rlu.ru/r/13120/http%3A%2F%2Fwowslider.com%2Fru%2F

Comment: @HELOWORD Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Объясните конкретнее. Вам нужно как бы окошко, в котором можно листать фотографии вперед назад? И интересуют именно обработчики событий? Выложите код, даже неправильный этого - он поможет понять, что вам нужно.

Comment: всё, уже разобралась :)) спасибо ребята, что не оставили без внимания